# How to replace a paragraph with formatting text using xceed docx?

Tags: c#, ms-word, docx, xceed

I want to replace some text in a `docx` file, and i'm using `XCeed Docx` lib, i want to ask if there is any way to replace the text with a new formatted text? For exemple i have the `%value%` (normal text) and i want to replace it with **bold text** to replace only the text i use the function `document.ReplaceText(%value%, "Bold text")`. Remark not all the replace text need to be bold and i do not know if the next is bold or not, i need the bold text only in some situations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
Formatting formatting = new Formatting();
formatting.Bold = true;
doc.ReplaceText("%value%", "Bold Text", false, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.None, formatting);
```